# How can I save the HICON as file in Go

Tags: windows, go, winapi, icons

I can get the HICON with [ExtractIconW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-extracticonw)

for example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func MakeIntResource(id uintptr) *uint16 {
    return (*uint16)(unsafe.Pointer(id))
}

const IDI_QUESTION = 32514

func main() {
    user32Dll := syscall.NewLazyDLL("User32.dll")
    procLoadIconW := user32Dll.NewProc("LoadIconW")

    hIcon, _, _ := syscall.SyscallN(procLoadIconW.Addr(),
        0, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(MakeIntResource(IDI_QUESTION))),
    )
    log.Println(hIcon)
}
```

But I don't know what I should do next to save HICON as a file (bitmap format is enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [code](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/go-pkg/blob/39899233750c4c20a82073c8ecbac1fa7bec5898/v2/w32/gdi32_func_test.go#L301-L419) is an example which writing by go, and it saves one of the resources to a bitmap file.

```golang
// Step:
// get HICON
// get ICONINFO from HICON
// get Bitmap from ICONINFO
// save Bitmap to a File
// Note: To make the example look simple, I ignore all possible errors handling.
func Example_saveFileIconAsBitmap() {
    user32dll := w32.NewUser32DLL()
    kernel32dll := w32.NewKernel32DLL()
    gdi32dll := w32.NewGdi32DLL()

    var hIcon w32.HICON
    {
        // Because I already know the iconID(myResourceID) I want, I can load it directly.
        // If you want to find the appropriate iconID after searching through RT_GROUP_ICON you can refer to this example:
        // https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/go-pkg/blob/34e5d2c1fc97bf149bf626acaaf8773fe1509d64/v2/w32/kernel32_func_test.go#L331-L353

        hmExe := kernel32dll.LoadLibrary("./testdata/exe/writeWithFont.exe") // writeWithFont.exe is in here: https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/go-pkg/tree/983a2c1/v2/w32/testdata/exe
        myResourceID := uintptr(1)                                           // You can use resourceHacker.exe to help you find the ID.
        hRes, _ := kernel32dll.FindResource(hmExe,
            w32.MakeIntResource(myResourceID),
            w32.MakeIntResource(w32.RT_ICON),
        )
        hMem, _ := kernel32dll.LoadResource(hmExe, hRes)
        lpResource := kernel32dll.LockResource(hMem)

        hIcon = user32dll.CreateIconFromResourceEx(lpResource,
            kernel32dll.MustSizeofResource(hmExe, hRes), true, 0x00030000,
            32, 32, // size X, Y
            w32.LR_DEFAULTCOLOR,
        )
    }

    var iInfo w32.ICONINFO
    {
        if !user32dll.GetIconInfo(hIcon, &iInfo) {
            return
        }
        // Remember to release when you are not using the HBITMAP.
        defer func() {
            _ = gdi32dll.DeleteObject(w32.HGDIOBJ(iInfo.HbmColor))
            _ = gdi32dll.DeleteObject(w32.HGDIOBJ(iInfo.HbmMask))
        }()
    }

    bmp := w32.Bitmap{}
    {
        // Create BITMAP by ICONINFO
        gdi32dll.GetObject(w32.HANDLE(iInfo.HbmColor), int32(unsafe.Sizeof(bmp)), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&bmp)))
    }

    // Save Bitmap to a file.
    var (
        bitmapFileHeader w32.BitmapFileHeader // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header
        bitmapInfoHeader w32.BitmapInfoHeader // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#DIB_header_(bitmap_information_header)
    )
    {
        bitmapInfoHeader = w32.BitmapInfoHeader{
            Size:  uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(bitmapInfoHeader)), // 40
            Width: bmp.Width, Height: bmp.Height,
            Planes:      1,
            BitCount:    32,
            Compression: w32.BI_RGB,
        }
        bmpSize := ((bmp.Width*int32(bitmapInfoHeader.BitCount) + 31) / 32) * 4 /* uint32 */ * bmp.Height // see the wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Pixel_storage

        sizeofDIB := 14 + uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(bitmapInfoHeader)) + uint32(bmpSize)
        bitmapFileHeader = w32.BitmapFileHeader{
            Type:       0x4D42,    // BM. // B: 42, M: 4D  //  All of the integer values are stored in little-endian format
            Size:       sizeofDIB, // HEADER + INFO + DATA
            OffsetBits: 14 + uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(bitmapInfoHeader)),
        }

        hdc := user32dll.GetDC(0)

        var lpBitmap w32.LPVOID
        hDIB, _ := kernel32dll.GlobalAlloc(w32.GHND, w32.SIZE_T(bmpSize))
        lpBitmap, _ = kernel32dll.GlobalLock(hDIB)
        defer func() {
            kernel32dll.GlobalUnlock(hDIB)
            kernel32dll.GlobalFree(hDIB)
        }()
        gdi32dll.GetDIBits(
            hdc, iInfo.HbmColor,
            0,
            w32.UINT(bmp.Height),
            lpBitmap, // [out]
            &w32.BitmapInfo{Header: bitmapInfoHeader},
            w32.DIB_RGB_COLORS,
        )
        outputBmpPath := "testdata/temp001.bmp"
        // Write: FileHeader, DIPHeader, bitmapData
        {
            f, _ := os.Create(outputBmpPath)
            defer func() {
                _ = os.Remove(outputBmpPath) // Remove test data. If you want to see the result, delete this line to see the final data.
            }()

            // FileHeader
            _ = binary.Write(f, binary.LittleEndian, bitmapFileHeader)

            // DIP Header
            _ = binary.Write(f, binary.LittleEndian, bitmapInfoHeader)

            // bitmapData
            bmpDatas := make([]byte, sizeofDIB)
            var offset uint32 = 0
            for offset = 0; offset < sizeofDIB; offset += 1 {
                curByteAddr := unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(lpBitmap) + uintptr(offset))
                bmpDatas[offset] = *(*byte)(curByteAddr)
            }
            _ = binary.Write(f, binary.LittleEndian, bmpDatas)

            _ = f.Close()
        }
    }
    // Output:
}
```

Above code is [part of a third-party library](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/go-pkg/tree/39899233750c4c20a82073c8ecbac1fa7bec5898/v2/w32), but no other third-party resources are used.

It is no longer written as a single file because winapi has too many constants, variables, and types, and the declaration of the DLL is also very tedious.
If you are interested, you can download this library back. Its packaging is very simple. If you do not like to use other third parties to capture the relevant variables can be done.

---

The following pictures will help you understand the meaning of the parameters of [MAKEINTRESOURCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/resource-types) more easily.

[image]

Comment: Did you try using [Windigo](https://github.com/rodrigocfd/windigo) instead of calling all those WinAPI syscalls by hand?

Comment: Understanding `winapi` is more important than using the framework. You only need to learn it once, even if you don’t use go in the future. As long as you are in the windows system, these learnings will not be in vain.

Comment: I'm not talking about using a framework... I'm talking about using the bindings that someone else already wrote, instead of writing your own. You'll still use the raw WinAPI calls.

Answer (score 4):

A real .ico file usually contains multiple images of different sizes while a HICON is just a single image.

If the goal is to copy the original icon then you must [LoadLibraryEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexw) as a datafile and then use the resource functions to first find the [RT_GROUP_ICON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/resource-types) and once you have that you know the `RT_ICON` ids and you can extract the sub-images and write your .ico.

If you still think you want to save a HICON, call [GetIconInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-geticoninfo) to get the image.

There are no low-level Windows functions to write .ico files. You can try GDI+ or WIC or write them yourself. The file format is very close to the resource format (stores a file offset instead of a resource id).

A guide to Windows icon formats [starts here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101018-00/?p=12513)...